# Guitar build — Will the wrong neck work?

Tags: electric-guitar, construction

I am building a Les Paul style guitar from parts I bought online.

Unfortunately, I noticed that I've got the wrong neck, the body is cut for a set-in neck with a tab at the end of the heel which goes into the bottom of the neck pickup cavity. The neck I have does not have this tab.

Can I still use it, because it fits into the body quite nicely? Or will this create a weak spot in the back of the body itself?

Comment: Maybe you could give some pictures?

Comment: I'm not a big LP guy, but I think what your body wants and your neck doesn't have is called a "long neck tennon". I have no opinion about whether that'll lead to problems to your build. Maybe look into luthier forums elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that Les Paul style guitars have set necks. Their necks aren't bolt/screw on, like, say, Strats. 'Fits the body quite nicely' - I'd want it to be such a fit that it'd need a vice or such-like to press the two together. There's also the neck angle to work out - that's pretty well dictated by the pocket and the shape of the neck heel. May/may not work.

If it was mine, I'd expect to glue and screw. Consider also where fret 12 will sit once it's in place - there's only so much adjustment in saddles, or where the bridge will go, for good intonation. Once glued and screwed, properly, it will be strong enough but use a good quality 2 part epoxy, and remember once it's fixed, it's fixed.

Comment: ”once it's fixed, it's fixed“ … not if you do it the guitar builder’s way and use hide glue. Resetting the neck on old guitars is not that uncommon. Won’t probably work out with epoxy though.